# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar al nivel de ejecución 1(monousuario) para realizar tareas de mantenimiento/administrativas en Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

Verán, estoy comenzando a estudiar los niveles de ejecución sobre los sistemas Unix y leí que el nivel 1 (monousuario) es usado para tareas administrativas; también leí que, para hacer un cierre seguro del sistema y cambiar al nivel monousuario, se pueden usar los comandos init o telinit y shutdown, pero es recomendable que se utilice shutdown para que el cierre no sea abrupto y no se pierdan datos de los usuarios que estén trabajando en el sistema. (Eso lo leí [aquí](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ssa/library/l-lpic1-101-3/index.html)
, en la pestaña 'apagado limpio')

Mi pregunta es, si ya estoy en el nivel 1 haciendo tareas de mantenimiento, cuando termine ¿como le hago para regresar al nivel en el que el sistema estaba operando antes? 
Por ejemplo: suponiendo que tengo un equipo en donde el nivel por default es multiusuario con inicio gráfico, y como administrador necesito instalar un componente x en el equipo. Entonces según lo que invetigué, para reiniciar el equipo puedo utilizar

```
shutdown -r 15
```

para indicarle al resto del usuarios que guarden su trabajo por que el equipo se va a reiniciar en 15 minutos. Una vez que se reinicie el equipo el nivel de ejecución será el 1 (monousuario). Cuando yo, como adminstrador, termine de trabajar en el equipo y necesite regresar al nivel multiusuario, ¿lo puedo hacer reiniciando el equipo o tengo que especificar con el comando init a que nivel quiero cambiar?

Pude conseguir un equipo con Ubuntu donde el nivel por default es el multiusuario con inicio gráfico. Y cuando estoy como root y reinicio el equipo, el nivel no se cambia al 1, sino que se vuelve a iniciar con el nivel predeterminado.

Answer (score 2):

Edito y amplío comandos:
Los niveles de ejecución se definen en cada distro de una manera. Por ejemplo, en Slackware el nivel 1 es monousuario con entorno de red; el 2 no se usa, aunque está configurado como 3; el 3 es es el entorno por defecto, multiusuario sin entorno de escritorio; el 4 multiusuario con X11 (entorno de escritorio); el 5 no se usa y el 6 es reboot de sistema. El nivel 0 es halt (apagado), mediante un enlace simbólico a 6.
No será muy diferente en otras distros, aunque la mayoría por defecto arrancan en modo multiusuario con X11 (creo Debian y derivados este nivel lo configuran en 5). El fichero que los define es /etc/inittab:

```
alfonso@Sherwood:~$ cat /etc/inittab 
#
# inittab   This file describes how the INIT process should set up
#       the system in a certain run-level.
#
# Version:  @(#)inittab     2.04    17/05/93    MvS
#                                       2.10    02/10/95        PV
#                                       3.00    02/06/1999      PV
#                                       4.00    04/10/2002      PV
#                                      13.37    2011-03-25      PJV
#
# Author:   Miquel van Smoorenburg, <miquels@drinkel.nl.mugnet.org>
# Modified by:  Patrick J. Volkerding, <volkerdi@slackware.com>
#

# These are the default runlevels in Slackware:
#   0 = halt
#   1 = single user mode
#   2 = unused (but configured the same as runlevel 3)
#   3 = multiuser mode (default Slackware runlevel)
#   4 = X11 with KDM/GDM/XDM (session managers)
#   5 = unused (but configured the same as runlevel 3)
#   6 = reboot

# Default runlevel. (Do not set to 0 or 6)
id:3:initdefault:

# System initialization (runs when system boots).
si:S:sysinit:/etc/rc.d/rc.S

# Script to run when going single user (runlevel 1).
su:1S:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc.K

# Script to run when going multi user.
rc:2345:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc.M

# What to do at the "Three Finger Salute".
ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t5 -r now

# Runlevel 0 halts the system.
l0:0:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc.0

# Runlevel 6 reboots the system.
l6:6:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc.6

# What to do when power fails.
pf::powerfail:/sbin/genpowerfail start

# If power is back, cancel the running shutdown.
pg::powerokwait:/sbin/genpowerfail stop

# These are the standard console login getties in multiuser mode:
c1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty --noclear 38400 tty1 linux
c2:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty2 linux
c3:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty3 linux
c4:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty4 linux
c5:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty5 linux
c6:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty6 linux

# Local serial lines:
#s1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -L ttyS0 9600 vt100
#s2:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -L ttyS1 9600 vt100

# Dialup lines:
#d1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -mt60 38400,19200,9600,2400,1200 ttyS0 vt100
#d2:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -mt60 38400,19200,9600,2400,1200 ttyS1 vt100

# Runlevel 4 also starts /etc/rc.d/rc.4 to run a display manager for X.
# Display managers are preferred in this order:  gdm, kdm, xdm
x1:4:respawn:/etc/rc.d/rc.4

# End of /etc/inittab
```

El fichero está impecablemente bien comentado: niveles de ejecución, scripts a los que se llama para cambiar de runlevel... En fin, no requiere añadidos.

Los cambios de nivel no son abruptos, los scripts a los que se llama están diseñados para cambiar de runlevel de manera "graceful".
Si tienes privilegios de superusuario puedes hacer:

```
init x
```

o

```
telinit x
```

para cambiar el nivel de ejecución, que a la postre no es más que el estado en el que se ejecuta tu máquina en ese momento. Obviamente, tendrás que cambiar la x por el nivel deseado.
Para apagar el sistema, los comandos halt y shutdown (a éste hay que definir le algún parámetro) son igualmente enlaces simbólicos a init 6:

```
shutdown -h now  # apagará el sistema en este momento. 
shutdown -h 3 #  apaga en 3 minutos.
```

Te respondo porque me la sé, y algo he de colaborar en el sitio, que tanto me ha dado. 
Pero poco has buscado en Google; ningún código (ningún intento) has mostrado, y la pregunta no es estrictamente de programación. 
Nos llevaremos los dos un tirón de orejas. 
Serái conveniente que hicieses el [recorrido por el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)